# Return String Value From Ajax Query

Tags: jquery, ajax

This may be a lack of truly understanding jQuery, but I am trying to create a function that calls a handler that return a single string value (a concatenation of several strings in a sql query). These values are then combined and saved as one string value and returned and stored as a variable for later use.

I can confirm the hanlder works. The internal `displayList` variable does collect the proper information. That is not the issue. The issue is how to return this output value to the original call.

Below is a sample.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get Drop Down List Options
    var listValues = populateDropDown(9);

    // Returns "" Instead Of Full String
    alert(listValues);         
});

function populateDropDown(iCategoryID) {

        var displayList = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: "queries/dh_getListInfo.ashx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                iCategoryID: iCategoryID,
            },
            responseType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                // Loop Through Values And Build String
                if (response.length != 0) {
                    $.each(response, function (index, row) {
                        for (var index in row) {
                            displayList += "<option value=\"" + row[index].value + "\">" + row[index].value + "</option>";
                        }
                    });
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('fail');
            },
        });

        return displayList;

};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It was not a lack of jQuery understanding but a lack of understanding the ***Asyncronous*** in **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for the link!